# Can't find popular deep links for social apps in React Native

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

i want to create a sharing system in my RN app without using third party packages on npm, but using `Linking.openURL()`.

I can't seem to find any popular deep links for apps like Facebook, instagram, etc..

I only managed to open the apps using `fb://` or `instagram://` but if i want to create a new post on Facebook or send a direct message in Instagram, i've searched all googles and read all developers apis and s found nothing.

There is the same action on twitter for example where you redirect to the instagram app to sending a new direct message.. is there a way i can log or inspect the deep link from there on emulator?

Any ideas? solutions?